# Apply CSS based on calculation using Angular

Tags: angularjs, css, ng-class, ng-style

I've got a reading that comes in every few seconds.

Currently I'm using thresholds to determine when the animation should take place:

```
<div ng-class="{'circle1': speed < 10, 'circle2': speed < 13 && speed >= 15, 'circle3': speed >= 15}"></div>
```

Speed is already updating automatically but at the moment the css style only changes when  is goes above 13 and then 15 etc. Instead I want it to dynamically change as the speed changes. So 13.1 produces a larger circle than 13 and 13.2 is larger than 13.1 etc.

```
circle1 {
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    left: 128px;
    position: relative;
    background: green;
}
```

is the css for circle1. I'd like it to continuously transition from say green to yellow based on speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can define you're speed in you're controller

```
$scope.speed
```

and try to affect you're duration to this variable.

For change the style dynamically try to define the style in you're markup :

```
<div class='circle' style='width:{{speed}}px;'></div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand. Speed is already updating automatically but at the moment the css style only changes when  is goes above 13 and then 15 etc. Instead I want it to dynamically change as the speed changes. So 13.1 produces a larger circle than 13 and 13.2 is larger than 13.1 etc.

Comment: Oh ok, define the style in u're markup and apply 'style=width:{{speed}}px;'

Comment: Sorry, could you provide an example? I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your speed variable on your controller's scope so that whenever speed will change, angular will revaluate the expression and apply the appropriate class. As Alexis said, use

```
$scope.speed
```

and class based on expression will be applied.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand. Speed is already updating automatically but at the moment the css style only changes when  is goes above 13 and then 15 etc. Instead I want it to dynamically change as the speed changes. So 13.1 produces a larger circle than 13 and 13.2 is larger than 13.1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
$scope.getSpeedClass = function() {
  var klass;
  if (speed <= 15) klass = 3;
  if (speed < 13) klass = 2;
  if (speed < 10) klass = 1;

  return klass;
}
```

```
<div class="circle{{getSpeedClass()}}"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently doing something similar. However, it still means I need to write the css for all individual "klass"es

Is there anyway that I can have a continuous transition on circle colour based on the speed?

Comment: do you use LESS/SASS? could loop things up. or just use `ng-style` and modify the style directly and not the class.